# Migrating to Google Cloud SQL using flyway, what jar files should be copied?

Tags: google-app-engine, flyway, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to migrate my database(MySQL) dump file Google Cloud SQL using flyway commandline tool. I have copied google_sql.jar to flyway-commandline-1.6/jars/ and set the following properties in flyway-commandline-1.6/conf/flyway.properties:

```
flyway.driver=com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver
flyway.url=jdbc:google:rdbms://myinstancename/devdb
flyway.user=myusername
flyway.password=mypassword
```

However, this doesn't work and produces the following error:

```
FlywayException: Error instantiating database driver: com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver
Occured in com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway in method configure, line number 789
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver
Occured in java.net.URLClassLoader$1 in method run, line number 217
```

Could somebody help me in identifying the required jar files for flyway to work with Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 2):

It's weird and poorly documented on AppEngine's side, but you must also copy the MySQL Jdbc Driver into `APPENGINE_HOME/lib/impl`

See: [Java Google App Engine and Google Cloud SQL running on local dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952696/java-google-app-engine-and-google-cloud-sql-running-on-local-dev-server)

Comment: This is of course for the local instance. For the remote instance, you should probably follow https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin_tools to authorize your machine.

Comment: Sorry for the lame question. Do I need to have appengine sdk to run flyway commandline?

Comment: Only if you wish to use it with Google Cloud SQL, otherwise no. This is an AppEngine/Cloud SQL limitation, not a Flyway one.