# JPA + Cloud SQL: How to design the persistence.xml

Tags: sql, xml, google-cloud-sql

I read the [Cloud-SQL JPA Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-jpatools).

When I click on "Connect", my connections to the cloud and the local mysql db do work.
But my EntityManagerFactory can't read the persistence.xml.

It's not clear for me how my persistence.xml has to look like, when I want to connect to my local mysql db.

In the tutorial it sounds like the persistence.xml-File is generated automatically and I have only to add my classes. Is that correct? If yes, what do I have to do to trigger automaitc generation?

Otherwise, how would it look like?

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work. These steps helped me to fix it, so that I could connect to my local mysql db:

- In `Project -> Properties -> JPA` I had to set the Connection to MyApp.MySQL.DevInstance
- In `Project -> Properties -> Google -> App Engine` you need to activate Use  'MySQL instance'
- Drop the mysql .jar in appengine-java-sdk-x.x.x/lib/impl.(see [Java Google App Engine and Google Cloud SQL running on local dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952696/java-google-app-engine-and-google-cloud-sql-running-on-local-dev-server))

You can see my persistence.xml below.

Comments:

- Don't set experimentally com.mysql.Driver as driver, it won't work.
- Set the MySQL property of Eclipselink

Hope this helps somebody ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.MyClass</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://myapp:instance1/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.platform.class.name" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My EntityManagerFactory looks like this:

```
package de.compareyourrace.system.server;

/*
 * Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * Factory for creating EntityManager.
 */
public final class EMF {
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance =
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
        return emfInstance;
    }

    private EMF() {
      // nothing 
    }
}
```