# No suitable driver found: jdbc:google:mysql

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jdbc, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to figure out why my App Engine (Endpoints) program will not connect and/or load the jdbc google mysql driver.

I have enabled the `<use-google-connector-j>` tag in **appengine-web.xml** and set it to `TRUE` as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j).

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>...</application>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>


    <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
</system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

And my endpoint method that tries to connecto the Google Cloud SQL:

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "lesson")
    public Lesson getLesson(@Named("id") int id) throws SQLException {


        // Create new lesson object
        Lesson l = new Lesson();

        // Create resultSet for database retrieval
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection c = null;
        // connect to the database
        // Connection c = DatabaseConnect();
        String talk = "";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.getStackTrace().toString();
            l.setLessonObjectives(e.getMessage());
        }

        String url = "jdbc:google:mysql://" + Constants.PROJECT_NAME + ":" + Constants.SQL_INSTANCE_NAME + "/" + Constants.SQL_DATABASE_NAME + "?user=root";
        try {
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            talk = talk + "..... And now i'm going to connect";
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            l.setLessonDescription(e.getMessage() + " ---- " + e.getErrorCode() + " ----- " + e.getSQLState());
        }

        // check to make sure there is a connection available
        // execute query and save it in a result set.
        if(c != null) {
            try {

                rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM se_lesson WHERE id = " + id);

                if (rs.first()) {

                    l.setLessonId(id);
                    l.setLessonName(rs.getString("lesson_name"));
                    l.setLessonObjectives(rs.getString("lesson_objectives"));
                    l.setLessonDescription(rs.getString("lesson_description"));
                    l.setLessonMinCoins(rs.getInt("lesson_min_coins"));
                    l.setLessonLevel(rs.getInt("lesson_level_id"));
                    l.setLessonColour(rs.getString("lesson_color"));

                } else {
                    l.setLessonId(-1);
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                l.setLessonId(-2);

            }
         }

        l.setLessonObjectives(talk);



        logger.info("Calling getLesson method");

        return l;
    }
```

And the error message returned when I call the endpoint through the APIs Explorer is:

```
{
 "lessonId": 0,
 "lessonDescription": "No suitable driver found for jdbc:google:mysql://stark-english:content-instance/stark?user=root ---- 0 ----- 08001",
 "lessonObjectives": "I think its loaded",
 "lessonMinCoins": 0,
 "lessonLevel": 0,
 "kind": "stark#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"2PYCr435swl6FqpdQwvud90MSME/LgtErz4rWHsMTKvNQvVMw3CDWhw\""
}
```

Any idea why this would happen even if I'm calling the google connector *and* it isn't returning a `ClassNotFoundException`?

**Update 1:**

Yes I've included the mysql connector in my Android studio project. As shown below:

[image: Build library]

[image: App Engine Module libraries/dependencies]

Comment: I suppose you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952696/java-google-app-engine-and-google-cloud-sql-running-on-local-dev-server. Basically add mysql-driver jar to the path and deploy it

Comment: Thanks, @AllahbakshAsadullah, but this didn't help. I'm currently using Android Studio to deploy my App Engine project. And I've checked to make sure that the mysql connector was included.

Comment: Can you actually tell which is the class which is not found. Is mysql-connnector already there in deployment folder which is getting uploaded to appengine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CloudSQL driver class name is: "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver". You are using: "com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver".

Note that depending on where you are opening the connection (locally or on the server) you will need to switch between driver as explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/).

To open the connection locally on a mysql server you need to use driver: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" and also modify the Connection URL appropriately.

Comment: This was it. I'm not sure how it got to: com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver, I could have sworn I copied and pasted the code straight out of the documentation. I guess not.

Comment: Thank you, btw. Saved me a huge headache.

Comment: No problem. Some of the worst errors I've ever created were caused by copy/paste ;-)

Comment: I got in the same error, it was not copy paste, just auto import. I don't know why AppEngine Sdk has that library.